# Convert month names to numbers in r

Tags: date, time, recode

I am using data that includes full month names:

```
months <- c("March",     "April",     "May",       "June",      "July",  "August",  "September")
```

Is there a function that will convert them to numbers?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `match()` with the built-in variable `month.name`.

```
match(months, month.name)
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Or convert your months variable to a factor and then an integer:

```
as.integer(factor(months, levels = month.name))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tidyverse method to rename Months

```
df %>%
mutate(month = recode(month,
  Jan = 1,
  Feb = 2,
  Mar = 3,
  Apr = 4,
  May = 5,
  Jun = 6,
  Jul = 7,
  Aug = 8,
  Sep = 9,
  Oct = 10,
  Nov = 11,
  Dec = 12
))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
months = 1:12
names(months) = month.name
months['March']
```

**OUTPUT**

```
March 
    3
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to link month numbers and names via a named vector

```
months <- c("March",     "April",     "May",       "June",      "July",  "August",  "September")
x <- setNames(1:12, month.name)
unname(x[months] )
```